# AWS RDS Postgres Connection issue to Microsoft Power BI: "The Remote certificate is invalid..."

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, powerbi, amazon-rds

Update:

We amended SSL requirement to optional and it worked without SSL Encryption. Note that we have an EC2 instance running an On-premises Data gateway which allows automated dataset refresh for our embedded dashboards.

Background:

I'm using embedded Power BI Dashboard that is connected to AWS RDS Postgres DB including an On-premises Data Gateway. When it was initially setup a year ago with `Pgsql` 14, it worked fine after updating the CA certificates and installing `npgsql-4.0.10` in addition to unchecking encryption option in Power BI Data Source setting.

The devs recently upgraded the RDS to PGSQL 15 and neither Power BI Desktop nor Power BI Cloud can connect to the DB anymore and gives this error:

> We encountered an error while trying to connect
> Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.'"

I updated CA from AWS RDS just in case, deleted old ones, reinstalled Power BI Desktop but in vain.

Upon attempting to use ODBS PGSQL connector, it managed to connect Power BI Desktop to the DB but Power BI Cloud Service couldn't connect.

any help is appreciated.

I tried to follow all relevant instructions in Power BI Documentation on Postgres connection and expected to be able to connect Power BI Cloud / Desktop to the upgraded RDS PGSQL 15 DBs

Most online posts about this issue predate PGSQL 15 and don't solve the problem

Comment: Can you find the error in the database server's log?  Sometimes that contains additional information compared to the client error.

Comment: I could not find any errors. We had to downgrade SSL and remove enforcement. When I unticked encrypt connection from the data source setting in Power BI Desktop the connection work (Did the same in PBI Cloud)

It's annoying that the level of support when using non-Microsoft cloud services is almost non-existent.

Comment: Can you connect over ssl with someone simpler to debug with, like `psql`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the AWS RDS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html):

> You can require that connections to your PostgreSQL DB instance use SSL by using the rds.force_ssl parameter. **The default rds.force_ssl parameter is set to 1 (on) for RDS for PostgreSQL version 15.** All other RDS for PostgreSQL major version 14 and older have the default value for rds.force_ssl parameter set to 0 (off).

Since the connection from Power BI Desktop relies on a workaround which disables encryption, this new default of RDS is incompatible with it.

The solution is simple: override the `rds.force_ssl` flag to `0` in the parameter group used by your RDS instance.

Comment: Thank you, that's what we did and it worked but honestly it isn't 100% satisfactory since you're downgrading the security of your connection.

Comment: I agree it's a suboptimal workaround, but it's not a downgrade of security, since the previous solution was equally insecure. After all, you mentioned in your post about "unchecking encryption option in Power BI Data Source setting", so the connection was also unencrypted and RDS was also allowing unencrypted connections before version 15.